# Power series representation of $f(x) :=$ $1 \over {1 + 4x^2}$

Tags: power-series

> Let
>
> $f:$ ($-1 \over 2$, $1 \over 2$) $\rightarrow \Bbb R$,
>
> $f(x) :=$ $1 \over {1 + 4x^2}$
>
> be a function.
>
> I am searching for a power series representation of this function.

I solved this the following way:

We know that

$1 \over {1 - x}$ $= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n.$

Therefore,

$1 \over {1 + 4x^2}$ $=$ $1 \over {1 - (-4x^2)}$ $=$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-4x^2)^n$ $=$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n 4x^n 2^n$

Comment: which unfortunately is wrong. You were doing fine until the very last step. Maybe there is a formatting error. Does it display the way you intended?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I intended.

Comment: Oh, no, it's actually not, haha. I wrote that up totally different before, the way it was mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost:

$$(-4x^2)^n=(-(2x)^2)^n=(-1)^n(2x)^{2n}=(-1)^{n}x^{2n}2^{2n}=(-1)^nx^{2n}4^n$$

Comment: Thanks! What mathematical law tells me that I have to pull out $(-4)^n$ first and not, like I did, $(-1)^n$?

Comment: Oh, and you changed the $4$ into a $2$?

Comment: @user351609 He was just saying that since $4$ equals $2^{2}$, you can write $4x^{2}$ as $2^{2}x^{2}$, and now since they have the same power you can "pull the power out" as $(2x)^{2}$.

Comment: @user351609 Also, to your first question, you don't *have* to pull out the $(-4)^{n}$ first, but to skip writing this down is to skip writing a step down.  And when you don't write every step, you can easily make mistakes.  We know $(-4)^{n}$ is $(-1 \cdot 4)^{n}$, which gives us $(-1)^{n}4^{n}$.  Finally, in your original work, you forgot that $(x^{2})^{n} = x^{2n}$.  When you raise something with a power to another power, you can multiply the powers together.

Comment: @user351609: This is a good answer, but it isn't quite correct about one thing. The power series converges wherever $$\bigl\lvert-4x^2\bigr\rvert<1,$$ or equivalently, $4x^2<1.$ One can show the interval of convergence to be precisely the domain of $f$.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was struggling in and so I kept editing my answer @CameronBuie